# API /Symfony Request http return 404

Tags: php, apache, symfony, phpunit

I'm trying to test an action which has email as a parameter.
Here is code:

```
$client = static::createClient();
$crawler = $client->request('GET', '/api/register/emailverification/',
                            array('email' => 'email@gmail.com'));
$response = $client->getResponse();

$this->assertEquals(200, $response->getStatusCode());
```

But it returns 404 error.

PS: when I test this in the url it works fine!

Comment: host is missing in url

Comment: I tried to add it using those lines :$host = $client->getContainer()->getParameter('http://127.0.0.1:8000');
        $client->getContainer()->get('router')->getContext()->setBaseUrl($host); but still other error :The parameter "http://127.0.0.1:8000" must be defined.